# update xml with xpath

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

I want to change the rating of jojo restaurant only , i tried this code but didn't work please help.  Below is my xml document and the code I have.

```
<city> 
    <beirut> 
        <restaurant> 
            <name>sada</name> 
        </restaurant> 
    </beirut>  
    <jbeil> 
        <restaurant> 
            <name>toto</name>  
            <rating>4.3/5</rating> 
        </restaurant>  
        <restaurant> 
            <name>jojo</name>  
            <rating>4.3/5</rating> 
        </restaurant> 
    </jbeil>  
    <sour> 
        <restaurant> 
            <name>sada</name> 
        </restaurant> 
    </sour> 
</city>
```

Code:

```
  try {
     File inputFile = new File("src/xpath/josephXml.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory 
        = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

     dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

     XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

     String expression = "/City/Jbeil/Restaurants/Restaurant[name='Feniqia']/rating"; 


     Element e = (Element)xPath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

     if (e != null){
        e.setTextContent("5/5");
     }

  } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
  }
```

Comment: What's "didn't work" mean? What did it do or not do? Also, you're throwing away the exception in the catch, instead print it out, it may have useful information.

Comment: the rating stay the same , 4.3

Comment: xpath expressions are case sensitive, `City` != `city`, ...

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to write the result (there are other ways):

import java.io.File;

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;


try
{
Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result out = new StreamResult(new File("result.xml"));
Source in = new DOMSource(doc);
trans.transform(in, out);
}
catch (Exception exe)
{
System.err.println(exe.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your XPath did not align to your posted XML (no `<restaurants>` or `Feniqia` name) and all should have been lower case. Possibly you extracted a piece from large xml document. For demonstration, I used the `jojo` restaurant.

Second, XPath does not itself update an XML, you will need to create a new document. Simply add a transformation at end:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class RatingUpdate {    

    public static void main(String [] args) {

          try {
               File inputFile = new File("src/xpath/josephXml.xml");

               DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
               DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

               dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

               Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
               doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

               XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

               String expression = "/city/jbeil/restaurant[name='jojo']/rating"; 

               Element e = (Element)xPath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

               if (e != null){
                  e.setTextContent("5/5");
               }

               Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
               xformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File("src/xpath/josephXml_update.xml")));

             } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException |
                      TransformerException e) {

          }
    }
}
```